# AngularJS load partials in the beginning and not at when needed in django?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, django

I have the template folder in django where all the templates/partials for my app resides. I want to load all my partials to the template cache of the angular at the beginning instead as per controller request.

I have route setup like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []).
config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
    when('/landing', {
        templateUrl: '/landing-partial',
        controller: landingController
    }).
    when('/:wkspId/query', {
        templateUrl: '/query-partial',
        controller: queryController
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/landing'
    });
}]);
```

I want to solution similar to this rails gem(https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates) in django.

Comment: You can use your build system (grunt/gulp etc) to generate a .js file as an angular module from your html templates and include that in your index.html. Angular will resolve templates from there if found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your build system, there are plugins that can take care of this for you.

For GruntJS:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-angular-templates

and for Gulp:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-templatecache

just point them to your html files and they will create a javascript file that looks like:

```
  angular.module('app').run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("home.html",
    // contents for home.html ... 
  );
```

and will resolve the templates from there instead of making an http request to fetch the actual files.
You just need to include this js file along with your app script tags and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert templates in index.html like here:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/landing-partial">
  Content of the template.
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/query-partial">
  Content of the template.
</script>
```

After that you can use these templates in your router:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []).
config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
    when('/landing', {
        templateUrl: '/landing-partial',
        controller: landingController
    }).
    when('/:wkspId/query', {
        templateUrl: '/query-partial',
        controller: queryController
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/landing'
    });
}]);
```

It works similar to provided by you module. After angular bootstrapping templates  will be put to $templateCache and can be used anywhere.